# How can I modify the protected values of a variable of a base class in a derived class function?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, protected

```
class abc{
protected:
    int x; 
};
class b: public abc{
public :
    void something(abc a){ a.x = 1;}
};
```

I get an error in the second last line stating that I cannot access member x of variable a.

> Error: Protected Member "abc::x" is not accessible through a "abc" point or object.

Is there another way to modify the x-value of variable a?

Comment: 1. Add getter/setter functions in the base class. 2. Pass this object to function `something` by reference, **not** by value. 3. Are you sure that's what you want to do (i.e., pass an `abc` object to a function of class `b` which inherits from class `abc`)? In the code you've published, there doesn't seem to be any point in the inheritance to begin with. Perhaps you originally intended to set `this->x = 1`, and got confused somewhere along the way...?

Answer (score 2):

You can do simply as follows in derived class

```
void something(){ x = 1;}
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0f6153abfe6b783

Answer (score 2):

Within `something()` you are in object scope, so you have a pointer to the current object with the `this` keyword. In C++, however, the default resolution within object scope, is the object's own scope, so you don't need to prefix it at all. Simply referring the property's name is enough to have the resolution succeed.

Answer (score 2):

When inheriting, `b` can modify the values of the base class "it" inherited, but the base `abc` protected class attributes of other objects are still protected and reserved for themselves. In this case the `abc` `a` object you pass through the function `something` is another object not associated with an object `b`.

Access modifiers work on class level, meaning within an object `b` the private attributes of another object `b` can be accessed. However, this inheritance shown is basically saying that "`b` is an `abc`, but `abc` isn't necessarily `b`". In the function `void something(abc a){ a.x = 1;}`, if you change it to `something(b a)` instead, it would work, because a `b` can access another `b`.

However, remember that if:

```
int main(){
    abc data;
    abc data2;

    data.x = data2.x; //This won't work becuase you are outside the class
}
```

What you can do is declaring class `b` a friend of class `abc`, so that any object `b` can access the protected members of any other object `abc`.

Example:

```
class abc{
protected:
    int x; 

friend class b;
};
```

Comment: Alternately, since objects of the same class can edit one another's values freely, you can simply add a protected setter function to the protected portion of `class abc` and use that to change `abc` objects' `private` and `protected` members. This will allow all inheriting classes to change `abc` values that have protected 'setter' functions, and no one else. [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb08a03c514caec9)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what you are asking is to have a function setX() in class ABC like such:

```
class abc
{
    public:
        void setX(int x){ this->x = x; }
    protected:
        int x; 
};
```

Then declare `something` inside of class B like this:

```
class b: public abc
{
    public :
        void something(abc a){ a.setX(1); }
};
```

At that point though you might as well not have class B at all, but rather from the scope you are calling `b.something(myABCObj)` just call `myABCObj.setX(1)` instead.

The point of 'protected' is that `class b` has access to 'x' in `class abc` not through the parameter you are passing it but rather **inside of itself**.

For example, your class b could look like this:

```
class b: public abc{
    public :
        void something(){ x = 1; } //HA- I inherited a value from class abc that wasn't public and changed it!
};
```

So in a different scope you could create object `b myB;` and `myB.x` won't be allowed but `myB` will have access to 'x' inside of itself from its parent class.